# Excitatory impulse speed vs inhibitory

Tags: neuroscience

Is there a difference in speed of impulses created by excitatory and inhibitory neurons?

Comment: It is possible that they are different since the ion channels expressed in different cell types are different. I do not know of any studies though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a wide variety of inhibitory neuron classes.  See here for a review of interneurons in the hippocampus: [P. Somogyi, T. Klausberger, J. Physiol. 562, 9–26 (2005).](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1113/jphysiol.2004.078915/full).

Different classes of interneurons have different spike durations (e.g. "fast-spiking" or FS cells, generally used as a marker of putative PV+ interneurons).  Additionally, different classes of interneurons have different post-synaptic receptors with specific temporal and other characteristics.  For example, GABA-A receptors have time constants of ~10ms, whereas GABA-B receptors have time constants of ~100ms (and yes, there are subtypes of those receptor classes).  You can see a modeling paper I wrote for exploration of a use for different receptor classes, as well as more references for further research. [H. Sanders, M. Berends, G. Major, M. S. Goldman, J. E. Lisman, J. Neurosci. 33, 424–429 (2013).](http://www.jneurosci.org/cgi/doi/10.1523/JNEUROSCI.1854-12.2013).